# Counting number of data and arranging them

Tags: php, mysql

Please can someone help me with this

I would like to count the number of entries in the database and also sort them correctly. Like in this website [www.songlyrics.com](http://www.songlyrics.com/)

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please post your code that you have tried. What is you table structure and desired layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use this my function to get what you want done. Hope your connection to the database is okay?

```
**function select_query($fields,$tables,$where="",$order_by="",$group_by="",$having="",$limit="") {   

    $sql_stat=" select $fields from $tables ";   

    if (!empty($where)) $sql_stat.="where $where ";   
    if (!empty($group_by)) $sql_stat.="group by $group_by ";   
    if (!empty($order_by)) $sql_stat.="order by $order_by ";   
    if (!empty($having)) $sql_stat.="having $having ";   
    if (!empty($limit)) $sql_stat.="limit $limit ";   

    return mysql_query($sql_stat) or mysql_error().",".mysql_errno();   
}**
```

I hope you can interpret that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
```

will give you the number of entries. What do you mean by "sort them correctly"? See the MySQL doc page for more examples.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

count :

```
Select Count(*) from table
```

Sort :

```
Select * from table order by songname   asc/desc
```

songname could be any field